# Binding data-objects with attributes in Polymer elements

Tags: asynchronous, polymer

I have 2 custom elements. A store that loads a bunch of data-objects from IndexedDB and a view that has to draw things on a `<canvas>` depending on these data-objects.

IndexedDB works asynchronous.

So I published an attribute in each custom element and bound them together, so when the IndexedDB callback resolves, it changes the published attribute of the store and the view will changed too by the Polymer data-binding mechanism.

The my-app template looks like this:

```
<template>
  <k-store data="{{bounddata}}"></k-store>
  <k-draw data="{{bounddata}}"></k-draw>
</template>
```

and sets the bounddata to `{}` to indicate this is an object.

In the store something like this happens:

```
data: null,
ready: function() {
  loaddatafromindexdb( function(theLoadedData) { 
    this.data = theLoadedData; 
  }.bind(this) );
}
```

In the view something like this should happen:

```
data: null,
attributeChanged: function( attribute ) {
   if( attribute == 'data' ) this.drawSomeStuffWithData();
}
```

Then I just have to implement `attributeChanged( attributeName )` in the view and the data can be used for rendering.

Somehow this whole thing results in an error in `ShadowDOM/src/wrappers/event.js` with an "InvalidCharacterError" even before `ready()` of the app templates is called. Probably while trying to bind the attribute, which is an object and treated as a string or something...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an interesting app!

First thing, instead of using the custom element `attributeChanged` callback, use a [property `*Changed` watcher](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#change-watchers) in the view element. The attribute itself isn't changing (e.g. `data="{{boundata}}"` doesn't change) but rather, the underlying property the attribute is bound to.To tap into that databinding system and be be notified when `boundata` changes, try:

```
boundataChanged: function(oldVal, newVal) {
  console.log(oldVal, newVal, this.data);
  // update canvas
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/godozowa/2/edit

As for the error, can you provide a jsbin that repos the error? Mock data would do.
Other than that, be sure to include `platform.js` before any other code that modifiers the DOM. In general, the sooner the better.

Comment: I had a `,` in my `<polymer-element>` tag, which caused the error. (`<polymer-element name="k-store", attributes="data">`)

Comment: The `bounddataChanged` method only gets called when I ad a new object and not when I change this object. This is bad for bi-directional communication.

Comment: If you're updating values or subobjects (e.g. the object itself is not completely replaced), you'll need to setup path observation: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#observeblock

Comment: Does this work for dynamic paths, too? I use the `data` object as container and don't know the names of future attributes in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with observer like the following.

```
Polymer({
  is: "your-element",
  properties: {
    bounddata: {
      type: Object,
      observer: 'dataChanged'
    }
  },
  dataChanged: function() {
     // code to refresh the element
  }
});
```